# What is "HDFS write pipeline"?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

While i was going through hadoop definitive guide, i stuck at below sentence:-

> writing the reduce output does consume network bandwidth, but only as
>   much as a normal HDFS write pipeline consumes.

Questions : 
1. Can some help me understand above sentence in more detail.
2. And what does "HDFS write pipeline" mean ?

Answer (score 3):

When files are written to HDFS a number of things are going on behind the scenes related to HDFS block consistency and replication. The main IO component of this process is by far replication. There is also the bidirectional communication with the name node registering the block's existence and state.

I think when it says "write pipeline" it just means the process of:

1. Creating the blocks
2. Registering with the NN
3. Performing replication
4. Doing write flushes to disk
5. Maintaining block state across the cluster (location, is-locked, last-updated, checksums, ect)

Answer (score 0):

Can be understood as follows:-

*Datapipeline is writing data to data nodes and no. of datanodes to be written is decided by replication factor, by default is it 3.

*Because reduce output will be stored at 3 different nodes, that is decided by data-pipeline. So network consumption will be equal to datapipeline to be written with data.

*we can understand the same with below diagram, where HDFS client gets location of datapipeline from NN and writes to it via handshake procedure involved in it.(handshake procedure is bit more complex here, we won't go in detail of it.) BTW diagram is taken from [Cloudera's site](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/02/understanding-hdfs-recovery-processes-part-1/)
[image: Data pipeline process]